# rosdep install specific version of dependencies

Tags: ros, rosdep, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's suppose I want to install scikit-image 0.15.0. I'm checking scikit-image lib within rosdep db (returns python-skimage-pip -> scikit-image). Then fill package.xml (as described [here](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html)) with

```
  <exec_depend version_eq="0.15.0">python-skimage-pip</exec_depend>
```

and type

```
rosdep install --from-path src/my_package
```

As a result I got scikit-image with newest version (0.18.1). How to force rosdep to follow defined version?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376259/rosdep-install-specific-version-of-dependencies/) by [definitive](https://answers.ros.org/users/57454/definitive/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2021-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosdep does not support specific version dependencies.

That feature was added to the package xml for enforcement between package versions.

Technically it would be possible to force a version installed for pip packages. However we specifically don't allow specifying versions as we have no way to generically do conflict resolution between packages which might declare different versions selected. Whereas the rosdep database is designed specifically to provide a consistent version that everyone that everyone can rely upon across the system.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [definitive](https://answers.ros.org/users/57454/definitive/) on 2021-04-16**:
So what is the proper way to install specific version of python packages within ROS project? Should I create a virtual environment, locate requirements.txt in package root and install it straight via pip? Seems unprofessional.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-04-16**:
Correct you should not generally override the version on the system. You can do it if you're only ever expecting users to work from source and that they will all know about the full system configuration and won't get suprised if another package with that same dependency starts failing due to the alternative version. (In reality that sort of user is only a power user/deployment expert. And even then they're not going to want to be working from source.)

It's generally not recommended to rely on a very specific version, but to make sure that your code is compatible with the standard versions available via package managers on the distro's target platforms.

To do it properly you should embed a virtualenv inside of your package and keep it isolated such that it won't interfere with any other packages in the workspace or on the system.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-17**:\

> So what is the proper way to install specific version of python packages within ROS project? Should I create a virtual environment, locate requirements.txt in package root and install it straight via pip?

It's not necessarily official or proper, but [catkin_virtualenv](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin_virtualenv) was created to do what you describe, while still being 100% compatible with the regular Catkin workflow and ROS workspaces.

It basically does what @tfoote suggests ("embedding a venv inside your package"), but in a more automated way.

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2023-03-21**:
@gvdhoorn is that ROS 1 specific? is the same available for ROS 2?

Also, there's currently a PR open to make rosdep support versions in pip:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/694

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-03-21**:
`catkin_virtualenv` is only for ROS 1, as the `catkin` in the name implies.

There is a "ROS 2 port" (basically a rewrite) at [esol-community/ament_virtualenv](https://github.com/esol-community/ament_virtualenv). I'm not sure what the status of it is. It's been 4 years since I last looked at it.